# BuferredReader problems

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am having trouble reading from a file. Here is my code can anyone show me where I am wrong?

```
    public static Map<Route, List<Service>> read(String fileName)
        throws IOException, FormatException {


    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String strLine;
    while((strLine = reader.readLine())!= null)       
      {
        /* Own Code */          
      }
    reader.close();
}
```

I am having a FileNotFound Exception. May this be a the location of my file that is wrong?

Comment: Care to tell us what the trouble is?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: To tell us where you're going wrong, you need to tell us *what* is happening.

Comment: *May this be a the location of my file that is wrong?* Yes, surely it is. Where have you put the file and how are you retrieving it?

Comment: I am just putting the name of the file. IN what folder should it be to just retrieve it by using the name of the file.

Comment: show us the path you added and the location from your file

Comment: In same folder where your compiled class file is.

Comment: It should be in the same location as the executable, class, or .jar file.

Comment: It should either be an absolute path (e.g. `c:\hello.txt` or `/hello.txt`) or one from the *current working folder* (e.g. `./hello.txt`, normally the folder from where you start the `java` executable. In IDE's you can normally specify the working folder.

Comment: @Lighthat Eh, no, that's not correct.

Comment: @SyamS That's called a resource I suppose.

Comment: I've tried putting it in the same folder as the .java file it is run from, but still nothing.

Comment: @user40380 That's called a resource I suppose. You should only do that for files that are part of your application itself. See my comment, or try and look up how to use resource files in Java.

Comment: @user40380 Try using an absolute path like @owlstead suggested. If you don't want to use absolute paths you have to use `./filename.txt` and make sure that the file is in the working directory as others have mentioned.

Comment: @owlstead, I am using the resource files. I am testing them Using Junit. And all of my searches for the testing code comes up as read Error. I will try to use a scanner instead. But thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to use a resource. A resource is not accessed as a file, it is better to use it [as a stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

```
InputStream resourceStream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceStream));
```

Above code takes the location of your class in account, so you can simply use the fileName as is, without a path, and place the fileName next to your `.java` file. It will automatically be placed next to the generated `.class` files and - when packaged - in your `.jar` file.

Comment: Try this, if you get an Exception, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just as owlstead commented keep in appropriate location and try like this

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(fileName);
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

i.e keep the file in classes folder or bundle with jar or current working directory etc.

Comment: That will work, but it will use the root of the package path and it uses an intermediate URL, which you can skip.